# NavigatorIOS error: undefined is not an object (evaluating routerArg.component)

Tags: react-native

Super, super basic React Native installation here; trying to add a simple NavigatorIOS instance to my application. I've populated NavigatorIOS with an `initialRoute` parameter, and set the component of that to another component, but I'm getting the error in the title at runtime. Here's an image of what I'm seeing.

[image]

## App.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, NavigatorIOS, TabBarIOS} from 'react-native';
import {HomePage} from './app/pages/Home';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu'
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
          <NavigatorIOS
              intitialRoute={{
                  component: HomePage,
                  title: 'Home'
              }}/>    
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

## Home.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {View} from "react-native";

export class HomePage extends Component<{}> {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    _onForward = () => {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            title: 'Scene foo',
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
          <View>
          </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Why am I seeing this? Running Xcode-10 beta, with the latest release of React Native, on macOS 10.14 Mojave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the typo here

```
<NavigatorIOS
   intitialRoute ={{ // <== here
     component: HomePage,
     title: 'Home'
}}/>
```

Replace `intitialRoute` with `initialRoute`

Comment: So the cause of my problem is literally my poor near-field eyesight; well now I feel really dumb. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, it took me a while to figure that out too :)